# Numpy-like methods for own classes

Tags: python, numpy, magic-methods

I have spent a day on chasing a bug on the following kind: I have a matrix `M`, which I used a `numpy.ndarray` for until now, on which I somewhere in the programm call `numpy.flip(M)`. I have decided that for some reason I want to replace my `M` with an instance of an own class `C`. When issuing `numpy.flip(M)` on this new `M`, it is returned without change (sure; I have never implemented any flipping method in `C`, and *without* warning (that, actually, makes me curious).

Now, I don't want to rewrite my code like

```
if isinstance(M, C):
    N = M.flip()
else:
    N = numpy.flip(M)
```

Does `numpy.ndarray` have some method that is called by `numpy.flip` such that I can implement a method of the same name in `C`? If there are such numpy-magic methods, are they documented somewhere?

Comment: ```numpy.ndarray``` has the ```__array_function__``` method which should get intercepted by ```numpy.flip```. You can read about it [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_function__)

Comment: `np.flip` is python code which you can read.  As shown in the docs it just applies a `::-1` indexing to the desired axis.

Comment: `np.flip` is a `numpy` function, not a method.  Some functions have wrappers to preserve subclasses.  Since `np.flip` just returns `m[indexer]`, it doesn't need anything extra.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it yet, @Kevin 's comment seems to be an answer.